# TypeScript how to enforce a type of multiple type options, Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Y'

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

In a data structure which is just an object, the keys are strings and the values can be another object or false (`{}` or `false`), iterating through the  values of the data structure and checking if it's an object and then mutating the nested data structure, it still errors, I assume because it *could* be a boolean - `Property 'X' does not exist on type 'boolean | Y'.` What is the best way to fix this? Example below:

```
type Definition = {
  [key: string]: string;
};

type Dictionary = {
  [word: string]: Definition | boolean;
};

function checkWorkds(words: Dictionary) {
  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(words)) {
    if (val !== false) {
      val['etymology'] = "idk"; // <--- Error here :sob:
    }
  }
}

const dict: Dictionary = {
  hello: {
    name: "hello",
    language: "english"
  },
  bob: false,
  hola: {
    name: "hola",
    language: "spanish"
  }
};

checkWorkds(dict);
```

The exact error in the example above is

```
Property 'etymology' does not exist on type 'true | Definition'.
  Property 'etymology' does not exist on type 'true'.
```

It seems that `if (typeof val !== 'boolean') {`seems to work, however I was curious if there is an alternative/The Right Way as this is a trivial example and in the production code we have lots of nested values that can either be other objects or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`boolean` type has `true` and `false`. Checking whether `val !== false` isn't enough; only `false` is eliminated, so there is still `Definition | true` left. You'll need to...

either (1) adjust `Dictionary` type to have only `false` value if you only use this Boolean value

```
type Dictionary = {
  [word: string]: Definition | false;
};
```

or (2) check `val !== false && val !== true` or `typeof val !== 'boolean'` so that there are no more `boolean` possibilities left in the union.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkWorkds(words: Dictionary) {
  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(words)) {
    if (typeof val !== 'boolean') {
      val['etymology'] = "idk"; // <--- no more error
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of `val !== false`, you should be comparing the `type` using `typeof`, this way typesript will know for sure that within the `if` clause has nothing to do with `boolean`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBLAdo4iD2yoF4oG8BYAKCigG0BrCEALigGdgAnFAcwF16nXk2BuEgF9BxEqEixEAY3RYAhsxC4CJMuQDuGZgBNuLdl1gIUaTNgA%20UAEYYMAGwjzkokSRLwArslnmo0gAsIaUoAdW1KHQYACi1dBnoYGTlkRRAASlVSKHhtKGjHYApqEAAaKAA3eXsOKAx4KAB5awArYOAAOghkAwgYuKj0zKJsskQG6IkIesrqqABCHDwAclsHJ2Rl4bUyXar7cmWIUABbBww2EGXavAAiRB1KW-4oAHpXqAAeAFpfqABRZjMPJBZjQWgMDDWWg7MhCHbw4iIkjSLBMKA6ZKJZLmNIqEZkIL2ewYegE3apE4Qei3Ikk26lWFQezONieeRsalQW7dNj2RAMAK3BGM7K2aE5aoMCCiwkOeRkpmUrm0%20UMpksvjszk0hhgZwCoUI4SiFFBELhZiRGKY2TpURAA)

Answer (score 0):

**For checking the exact type you want to have, use an equal operator so you won't have any issue if you add more types to `Dictionary` in the future.**

```
function checkWorkds(words: Dictionary) {
  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(words)) {
    if (typeof val === 'object') { // <--- Instead of typeof val !== 'boolean'
      val['etymology'] = "idk";
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Ex:**
Checking type if `!==` you will be having type error if adding `string` to the union:

```
type Dictionary = {
  [word: string]: Definition | boolean | string;
};
```

[image]